# Why is my stack returning null?

Tags: c, stack

I've been writing a simple stack in C:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

// Crude stack.
typedef struct Stack {
    int size;
    void **top;
} Stack;

Stack *stack_new() {
    Stack *stack = malloc(sizeof(Stack));
    stack->size = 0;
    stack->top = 0;

    return stack;
}

void stack_free(Stack *stack) {
    if (stack->size > 0) {
        free(stack->top);
    }
    free(stack);
}

void stack_push(Stack *stack, void *item) {
    stack->size++;

    // We copy the existing stack to a new place in the heap, then
    // write the pointer to ITEM to the top of the stack.
    void *old_top = stack->top;
    void *new_top = malloc(stack->size);
    memcpy(new_top + sizeof(void*), stack->top, (stack->size - 1) * sizeof(void *));
    stack->top = new_top;

    free(old_top);

    *stack->top = item;
}

void *stack_pop(Stack *stack) {
    if (stack->size < 1) {
        printf("WARNING: Popping of empty stack!\n");
    }
    stack->size--;

    void *old_top = stack->top;
    void *item = *stack->top;

    void *new_top = malloc(stack->size);
    memcpy(new_top, stack->top + sizeof(void *), stack->size * sizeof(void *));
    stack->top = new_top;

    free(old_top);

    return item;
}

int main() {
    Stack *stack = stack_new();

    stack_push(stack, "foo");
    stack_push(stack, "bar");
    stack_push(stack, "baz");

    printf("top of stack: %s\n", (char *)stack_pop(stack));
    printf("top of stack: %s\n", (char *)stack_pop(stack));
    printf("top of stack: %s\n", (char *)stack_pop(stack));

    stack_free(stack);

    return 0;
}
```

However, accessing values after popping the stack just gives me null pointers:

```
$ gcc -Wall stack.c 
$ ./a.out 
top of stack: baz
top of stack: (null)
top of stack: (null)
```

What have I done wrong? It compiles without warnings.

Comment: Did you try to run your code in a debugger? What was the result?

Comment: Also... what is the size of your `item`s? What would `new_top + 1` be in the call to `memcpy()`?

Comment: Ah, I'm assuming `item` is one machine word (one pointer).

Comment: Your assumption is incorrect. In fact that code fails to compile on non-gcc with an error "unknown size of `void*`" :) And even if the `sizeof(void*) == 4` it still doesn't necessarily guarantee that the pointer arithmetic on `void*` is well-defined

Comment: I've corrected the arithmetic and correcting the leaks that valgrind has pointed out.

Comment: Using `new_top + sizeof(void*)` is not "correcting" but is rather a different type of hack, I'm afraid.

Comment: `void *new_top = malloc(stack->size);memcpy(new_top + sizeof(void*), stack->top, (stack->size - 1) * sizeof(void *));` : wrong.

Comment: `void *new_top = malloc(stack->size);` is allocating **wrong** amount of memory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `stack_push()`:

```
void *new_top = malloc(stack->size);
memcpy(new_top + sizeof(void*), stack->top, (stack->size - 1) * sizeof(void *));
```

This has several problems:

- You are allocating the wrong size. You want to allocate `stack->size` number of items times the size of whatever `stack->top` points to.
- You must not call `memcpy()` when `stack->top` is 0. The behaviour is undefined if you copy to or from a null pointer.
- You try to perform pointer arithmetic on a `void *`. This is a compiler extension (eg. gcc) and is not possible in standard C.

The easiest way to solve these problems is to declare `new_top` to be the same type as `stack->top`:

```
void **old_top = stack->top;
void **new_top = malloc(stack->size * sizeof *new_top);
if (stack->top) {
  memcpy (new_top + 1, stack->top, (stack->size - 1) * sizeof *new_top);
}
stack->top = new_top;
```

Similarly, in `stack_pop()`:

```
void **old_top = stack->top;
void *item = *stack->top;

void **new_top = malloc(stack->size * sizeof *new_top);
if (stack->size) {
  memcpy(new_top, stack->top + 1, stack->size * sizeof *new_top);
}
stack->top = new_top;
```

Answer (score 2):

The code for pushing (and popping) the stack is wrong. Also, I was confused for a while reading your code because `top` actually represents array of stack elements, not just the top item.

In particular, `malloc` expects a number of bytes, however you have passed it a number of elements. And it is poor style to use `void *` when you mean `void **`.

I'd suggest making your code more readable by using `[]` notation and renaming `top`:

```
void **new_content = malloc( (stack->size + 1) * sizeof *new_content);
if ( !new_content)
     // error handling...

if ( stack->size > 0 )
    memcpy( &new_content[1], &stack->content[0], stack->size * sizeof *new_content );

new_content[0] = item;
free(stack->content);
stack->content = new_content;
++stack_size;
```

Now, this is actually about the worst possible way to implement a stack, in terms of efficiency. Every single push and pop operation you have to do an allocation and copy the entire stack. If you actually make your stack have its "top" at the end, then things become a whole lot simpler:

```
 void **new_content = realloc( stack->content, (stack->size + 1) * sizeof *new_content );
 if ( !new_content )
      // error handling...

 new_content[stack->size++] = item;
 stack->content = new_content;
```

Similar comments apply to your `pop` function in both varieties.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to not only debug, but to give a code review!

Answer (score 0):

Leaving aside many of the other problems in your code the "quick fix" is to allocate correct amount of memory:

```
void *new_top = malloc(stack->size * sizeof(void*));
```

And to fix the pointer arithmetic by using `char*` as your base pointer type:

```
// in stack_push()
memcpy((char*)new_top + sizeof(void*), stack->top, (stack->size - 1) * sizeof(void *));

// in stack_pop
memcpy(new_top, (char*)stack->top + sizeof(void *), stack->size * sizeof(void *));
```